# Is there a bundle that includes the old Visual Studio Tools like Spy++, Dependency Walker, etc. that came with Visual Studio 6.0?

Tags: visual-studio

I miss those tools sometimes, for example, when I have to know a window class so I can subclass it to override `WM_CONTEXTMENU` [to hide the context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38257948/303685).

I can download them one by one but was wondering if there is some place that includes a bundle with all of them in it?

Comment: Don't subclass the underlying window classes for WIndows Forms controls. They are implementation details. Just inherit from the control class and make the necessary modifications in your custom control.

Comment: Have a look in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools`.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you. I wouldn't want to, but there's an adamant context menu that shows up if you load a PDF document in a Web browser control even if you set all the control properties to disable it. I was wondering if I could handle `WM_CONTEXTMENU` and just dismiss this message altogether by not passing it along the `WndProc` chain after I have done nothing in response to it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton That's where I looked first before I posted this question but couldn't find either of the tools I mentioned.

Comment: If it's coming when a PDF document is loaded, then that's going to be some kind of Adobe plug-in that's displaying the context menu, in which case, subclassing the WebBrowser's window class is not going to make any difference. You'd need to subclass Adobe's PDF viewer. Guess the nice thing is, you can't make it any more broken than it already is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spy++ is still included with modern versions of Visual Studio, even up through VS 2015.

I don't know about Dependency Walker. It probably doesn't come with Visual Studio anymore, considering it has been deprecated for a while. Older versions of VS still ship with it, or it can be [downloaded separately](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) if you absolutely need it. [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is a better choice nowadays.

But as far as I know, these tools are still provided with the Windows SDK. The [current version (for Windows 10) is here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). If that doesn't have everything you're looking for, the [Windows 7 version here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) certainly does. Once installed, look in `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin`.

What else was there? WinDiff was there. I don't think that's included anymore. The last version of VS to come with it was VS 2010, and it wasn't in the Windows 7 SDK, either. I don't think this is a big loss. I used it one time because I didn't have another diff tool utility installed. My next move was installing [another diff utility](http://winmerge.org/)… MSVC 6/VS 98 also came with a bunch of OLE and ActiveX testing tools, which I don't think anyone uses anymore. I don't think these come with modern versions of the SDK, either, nor do I know where you can download them. Honestly, these are so before my time that I don't even know what you *do* with most of these tools. And then there's the *really* old stuff, the 16-bit utilities that were still being dragged along in a MSVC 6/VS 98 install. If these even still work on modern operating systems, I don't know why you'd want to use them.